# JAXB Bindings for code generation using CXF

Tags: java, jaxb, cxf

I am generating Java stubs from a WSDL using CXF codegen plugin and jaxb. In the bindings, I have specified that one particular object in one of the stubs has to be a String object even though the XSD has specified it as an integer.

The binding:

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../../../../../WSDL_Package/ABC/ABC_1.xsd">
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='TypeI']//xs:sequence//xs:element[@name='number']">
            <xjc:javaType name="java.lang.String" adapter="javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter" />
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
```

But on using the stubs in my project, I get the exception

> INFO: failed to create a new instance of class
>   javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter
>   java.lang.InstantiationException

Can someone help with resolving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter` is an **abstract** class and cannot be instantiated. You must implement your adapter.

```
public final class MyAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Type1,Type2> { ... }
```